# Meteorjs: Populate a select field with template names

Tags: meteor

I'm working on creating a small CMS using Meteor. In the CMS admin panel, the user has the ability to add pages. I'd like the user to be able to use a select dropdown to assign each page with a template. Is there a way to populate the select dropdown options with template names from a views folder or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could iterate over the keys of the `Template` object. You'd probably want to filter for some subset of the names. In this example, I just remove all of the ones that start with an underscore:

```js
var names = _.filter(_.keys(Template), function(name){return name[0] != '_';});
```

You may want to name all of the user-selectable templates with some common prefix to make this easier.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right direction. In my 'client' folder, I have a 'pages' folder, with a 'templates' subdirectory. The subdirectory contains 3 html files, which I would like to use to populate a dropdown.

I was thinking of using node's fs.readdirSync function but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Yeah that would probably work also, but it seems like it would be a little more complicated. You could have the server read and parse those files and then the client could access the names via a method call. In my solution, the names of the templates are already on the client, so you don't need to involve the server. However, unless you prefix/suffix the names, you wouldn't know what directory they came from. It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: So, you're method works in that I can store the names of the templates into a variable. Now, how do I parse through each value in the array and add it to a dropdown.

I'm thinking that I could have a template helper called getTemplates and then a handlebars block like {{#each getTemplates}} {{templateName}} {{/each}} but not sure how to wire that up.

Comment: I figured it out - I'll update my original question with my solution based on your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding reading files : as I understand it, meteor bundles and minimize your files when deploying?

Comment: Thanks - wow I can't believe I completely spaced out on that. So in production, meteor will compile your templates to javascript which will eliminate the possibility for the directory traversal technique mentioned above. I'll stick with my original answer. :)